# y minor grid is not showing. why?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Could you please tell me why minor grid lines are not showing in this graph?
Is this because I made ymin value to be greater than 0? It is set to 60 at the moment.

Thanks for your help!

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newtheorem{theorem}{THEOREM}
\newtheorem{proof}{PROOF}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{bigints}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{color,xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs,array}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{polynom}
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\usepackage{flexisym}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\newenvironment{tightcenter}{
\setlength\topsep{0pt}
\setlength\parskip{0pt}
\begin{center}}{\end{center}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
axis line style=thick,
axis lines=middle,
grid=major,
%
xminorgrids,
yminorgrids,
%
minor x tick num=4,
minor y tick num=4,
%
xmin=0,
xmax=7.2,
ymin=60,
ymax=101,
%
major grid style={line width=.2pt,draw=black!70},
%
height=11cm,
width=11cm,
%
%
tick label style={font=\large},
%
%
xlabel={\large Brand of remover},
ylabel={\large Concentration of acetone (\%)},
%
%
xtick={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7},
xticklabels={{},{Brand A},{Brand B},{Brand C},{Brand D},{Brand E}},
ytick={0,60,65,70,75,80,85,90,95,100},
%
xticklabel style = {xshift=+0.4cm},
%
clip=false,
%every tick label/.append style={font=\tiny},
ylabel style={
anchor=south,
at={(ticklabel* cs:1.0)},
yshift=1pt
},
xlabel style={
anchor=west,
at={(ticklabel* cs:1.0)},
xshift=1pt
},
xticklabel style={
rotate=-315
}
]
%\node[above] at (axis cs:1.0,1.04) {\Large \bf Graph of the Concentration of Acetone Per Brand};
%
\node[left] at (axis cs:0,60) {\large 60};
%%
\draw[thick,fill=gray!60](axis cs:1,60) rectangle (axis cs:2,96);
\draw[thick,fill=gray!60](axis cs:2,60) rectangle (axis cs:3,76);
\draw[thick,fill=gray!60](axis cs:3,60) rectangle (axis cs:4,85);
\draw[thick,fill=gray!60](axis cs:4,60) rectangle (axis cs:5,62);
\draw[thick,fill=gray!60](axis cs:5,60) rectangle (axis cs:6,70);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\newpage
\end{document}
```

[image: Current image]

Comment: Remove the `0` from the `ytick` list. You set `minor y tick num=4` and therefore the distance of the minor ticks is set to 60 / 4 = 15 (because the first distance between the `ytick`s is from 0 to 60). If you remove it, the distance will be calculated as 5 / 4 = 1.25 which is what you want.

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Comment: Please put this comment as the answer so I can give credit to you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remove the zero from the `ytick` list, since your plot starts from y = 60 anyways. In this case you can even omit the `ytick` option alltogether.

I am not fully sure that it is really like this, but I strongly guess that it is: PGF probably takes the distance of the first two values of the `ytick` list to calculate the minor grid ticks for the y axis. You define `ytick={0,60,65,70,75,80,85,90,95,100}` and `minor y tick num=4`, so PGF will divide 60 by 4 and set the distance of the minor y ticks to 15. This is, however, more than the distance between the following values of your `ytick` list and therefore, you don't see any grid lines on the y axis.

If you remove the zero (or the whole `ytick` list), PGF will set the distance of the minor y ticks correctly to (65 - 60) / 4 = 1.25.

I removed packages that are unnecessary for this example from your code. I suggest that you clean up your code since you load several packages multiple times and also packages that are already loaded by other packages or meant to replace older packages that you also load.

I'd further suggest that you use `axis x line = bottom, axis y line = left` instead of `axis lines=middle`, since this will add the tick at y = 60 automatically.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
axis line style=thick,
%axis lines=middle,
axis x line = bottom,
axis y line = left,
grid=major,
%
xminorgrids,
yminorgrids,
%
minor x tick num=4,
minor y tick num=4,
%
xmin=0,
xmax=7.2,
ymin=60,
ymax=101,
%
major grid style={line width=.2pt,draw=black!70},
%
height=11cm,
width=11cm,
%
%
tick label style={font=\large},
%
%
xlabel={\large Brand of remover},
ylabel={\large Concentration of acetone (\%)},
%
%
xtick={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7},
xticklabels={{},{Brand A},{Brand B},{Brand C},{Brand D},{Brand E}},
%ytick={0,60,65,70,75,80,85,90,95,100},                                     % <-- !
%
xticklabel style={xshift=+0.4cm},
%
clip=false,
%every tick label/.append style={font=\tiny},
ylabel style={
rotate=-90,
anchor=south,
at={(ticklabel* cs:1.0)},
yshift=1pt
},
xlabel style={
anchor=west,
at={(ticklabel* cs:1.0)},
xshift=1pt
},
xticklabel style={
rotate=-315
}
]
%\node[above] at (axis cs:1.0,1.04) {\Large \bf Graph of the Concentration of Acetone Per Brand};
%
%\node[left] at (axis cs:0,60) {\large 60};
%%
\draw[thick,fill=gray!60](axis cs:1,60) rectangle (axis cs:2,96);
\draw[thick,fill=gray!60](axis cs:2,60) rectangle (axis cs:3,76);
\draw[thick,fill=gray!60](axis cs:3,60) rectangle (axis cs:4,85);
\draw[thick,fill=gray!60](axis cs:4,60) rectangle (axis cs:5,62);
\draw[thick,fill=gray!60](axis cs:5,60) rectangle (axis cs:6,70);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I get the same result removing `ytick={0,60,65,70,75,80,85,90,95,100},`

Comment: Well, I tried to understand the reason why the minor grid is not shown. But you are right, in this case, the `ytick` option is not necessary at all.

Comment: Perhaps you could edit your answer. `ymin=60,
ymax=101,` are set above.